# Solving a recurrence equation

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve the problem

"A function $F(n)$ satisfies the recurrence $$F(n)\le4F(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)+n$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Give an upper bound for $F(n)$."

From what I can see, all that can be done is to write out the first few values of $F(n)$ to see if a pattern emerges, yet I can't find one...can anyone offer any hints?

Comment: An initial condition would be helpful.

Comment: Let $a,b \geq 0$ be two parameters to be specified later (and depending on initial conditions, possibly). Can you show by induction that $F(n) \leq an^2 - bn$?

Comment: I agree - there isn't one given though!

Comment: I suppose you should start with the most extreme case:

$F(n) = 4F(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)+n$